# help with remote file find/scp

Tags: ssh, find, cron, scp

I have a set of files on a remote sftp which I need to download to a server every day. sftp uses ssh keys to authenticate, so I created a ssh key and added to the remote server authorized folder. I'm able to ssh/sftp successfully manually. I h've creatd a script which first does a eval `ssh-agent -s` and then `ssh-add`. When run manually, we get a prompt for passphrase and scp works fine.

```
eval `ssh-agent -s`;
ssh-add;
#copy from remote to local
```

I need advice/best practice on how I can avoid keying in passphrase when I  add this crontab to run everyday.

Comment: Does the key you are trying to use have a passphrase?  You can avoid using ssh-agent/ssh-add by using the `-i` option on sftp.

Answer (score 1):

> I need advice/best practice on how I can avoid keying in passphrase when I add this crontab to run everyday.

Create a new `ssh` key with an empty password, specially for this task.  Save it in a file, say, `~/.ssh/cron`.  Add its corresponding public key to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the remote machine.  When you run your `scp` from `cron(8)` do it with the new key:

```bash
scp -i ~/.ssh/cron ...
```

That's all there is to it, you don't need `ssh-add`.

> eval `ssh-agent -s`

Contrary to the popular belief, this is **bad** practice.  `ssh-agent` doesn't get killed when you exit the terminal, and it stays with you for ever and ever, useless but fully authenticated, happily ever after.  You won't be able to connect to it, but it will always be there for some nifty trojan to discover and use.  You'll also accumulate many copies over time.

Do it like this instead:

```bash
ssh-agent /bin/bash -l
```

This spawns a shell, and exits when you quit said shell.  Don't try to script it, use it only for *interactive* sessions, and kill it as soon as you're done.

Comment: "Create a new ssh key with an empty password..." The OP could just remove the passphrase from the key file that he already has. `ssh-keygen` has an option to change the passphrase for an existing key file.

Comment: @Kenster: Probably not a good idea, for security reasons.  There really should be a dedicated key for unattended jobs, separate from the usual key for interactive logins, and the key should be restricted on the server in `authorized_keys`.  In fact, the unattended jobs should be run from an unprivileged, nologin account, not from an actively used one.